# Nodejs - make email templates dynamic

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express, mean-stack

I am developing project in MEAN STACK and I need to send many emails in my applications.
I have made email templates as separate all email templates, but I wants to make common header and footer in email templates.

> **Route.js**

```
router
    .route('/api/user/register')
    .post(
        //for get email template
        var fs = require("fs");
        var message = fs.readFileSync(basePath + "app/client/views/layout/registerEmailTemplate.html").toString();

        .......
);

router
    .route('/api/user/forgotpassword')
    .post(
         //for get email template
        var fs = require("fs");
        var message = fs.readFileSync(basePath + "app/client/views/layout/resetPasswordEmailTemplate.html").toString();

        .......
);


router
    .route('/api/user/accountActivation')
    .post(
        //for get email template
        var fs = require("fs");
        var message = fs.readFileSync(basePath + "app/client/views/layout/accountActivationEmailTemplate.html").toString();

        .......
);
```

> **registerEmailTemplate.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>My site title</title>
    <style>
        here all common css
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px">
        here registratin html code
</body>
</html>
```

> **resetPasswordEmailTemplate.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>My site title</title>
    <style>
        here all common css
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px">
        here resetpassword html code
</body>
</html>
```

> **accountActivationEmailTemplate.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>My site title</title>
    <style>
        here all common css
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px">
        here account activation html code
</body>
</html>
```

> **dependencies**

```
"express"  => "version": "4.13.4",
"mongoose" => "version": "4.4.4",
"mongodb"  => "version": "2.4.9",
"OS"  => "ubuntu 14.04 lts 32bit",
```

can any body give me a proper guidelines for generating dynamic email templates

Answer (score 0):

When I had to dynamically insert names into emails, I used string formatting on the html. This could still work for a template. First you have to add the format function to the string prototype.

```
if (!String.prototype.format) {
  String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
        ? args[number]
        : match
      ;
    });
  };
}
```

Then you can inject the templates into your emails.

```
router
    .route('/api/user/register')
    .post(
        //for get email template
        var fs = require("fs");

        var header = fs.readFileSync('pathToHeader');
        var footer = fs.readFileSync('pathToFooter');
        var message = fs.readFileSync(basePath + "app/client/views/layout/registerEmailTemplate.html").toString();

        var formattedMessage = string.format(message,header,footer);
);
```

Your email files would look like

```
{0}
        here resetpassword html code
{1}
```

Comment: Can you explain the format function execution.